# Compare numbers in Array using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a prob to solve, I have to use a loop to step through each position in
an array of " winning numbers"to check whether the variable customer number (input from keyboard) matches any of the winning numbers.
I must use a For loop to step through each position in the winning numbers array and to compare the customer number to each number the array contains.
I cannot use any method to achieve this problem
Thanks for your help!
 here what I did so far:

```
var customerNumbers = prompt("Enter your number:");
var winningNumbers = [12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43];    

for (var i = 0; i < winningNumbers.length; i++) {

    if (customerNumbers == 12 || //condition determinates the winning numbers
        customerNumbers == 17 ||
        customerNumbers == 24 ||
        customerNumbers == 37 ||
        customerNumbers == 38 ||
        customerNumbers == 43)
        alert("This week Winning numbers are:" + "\n" + "\n" + winningNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "The customer's Number is:" + "\n" + "\n" + customerNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "We have a match and a winner!");
} else {
    alert("This week Winning numbers are:" + "\n" + "\n" + winningNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "The customer's Number is:" + "\n" + "\n" + customerNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "Sorry you are not a winner this week");
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Above code not working?

Comment: What do you know about for loops? What have you tried? What didn't work with the solution you tried?

Comment: What do you mean with "I cannot use any method to achieve this problem"? Is this some sort of homework, otherwise that is kind of a silly constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below solution loops all the winning numbers and check for a match

```
var customerNumbers = prompt("Enter your number:");
var winningNumbers = [12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43];
var match = false;

for (var i = 0; i < winningNumbers.length && !match ; i++) {
  if (winningNumbers[i] == customerNumbers) {
    match = true;
  }
}

if (match)
  alert("This week Winning numbers are:" + "\n" + "\n" + winningNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "The customer's Number is:" + "\n" + "\n" + customerNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "We have a match and a winner!");
} else {
  alert("This week Winning numbers are:" + "\n" + "\n" + winningNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "The customer's Number is:" + "\n" + "\n" + customerNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "Sorry you are not a winner this week");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check whether `customerNumbers` exists in `winningNumbers`

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

*Script*

```
var customerNumbers=prompt("Enter your number:" );
var winningNumbers=[12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43];
if (winningNumbers.indexOf(parseInt(customerNumbers, 10)) > -1) 
    alert("This week Winning numbers are:"+"\n"+"\n"+winningNumbers+"\n"+"\n"+"The customer's Number is:"+"\n"+"\n"+customerNumbers+"\n"+"\n"+"We have a match and a winner!");
} else {
    alert("This week Winning numbers are:"+"\n"+"\n"+winningNumbers+"\n"+"\n"+"The customer's Number is:"+"\n"+"\n"+customerNumbers+"\n"+"\n"+"Sorry you are not a winner this week");
}
```

Comment: He said: it cannot use any method